# How can I stop Python mixing up subdirectories with the same name?

Tags: python, import, directory, pythonpath

I've got an application that is designed as a sort of wrapper for a number of open source repositories to run and then visualise the results from them.

The relevant parts of the project layout is as below:

```
project/
|--repos/
   |--repo1/
      |--utils/
      |--somecode.py
   |--repo2/
      |--utils/
      |--somemorecode.py
|--myapp/
   |--main.py
```

The file that is the entry point into my application is *main.py* within *myapp*. This calls into methods contained within *somecode.py* and *somemorecode.py* which return results.

The issue that I am coming across is that Python is looking at the wrong utils folder and therefore the imports are failing. For example, when I import a function from *somemorecode.py* into *main.py*, the file I am importing tries to access the *utils* folder located in *repo1*.

So far I have attempted modifications to PYTHONPATH, editing sys.path at runtime (obviously not recommended), but the former does not appear to solve the issue, and the latter threw up presumably caching issues due to having to flick between code from the two repos in fairly quick succession.

The repositories are open source GitHub repos which need to remain unmodified. These are not set up as packages as they are meant to be used as self contained applications, but I running them together for comparison purposes. Both of these repos contain utils packages with ***init**.py* files.

*somecode.py* uses imports such as `from utils.file import function`, and *somemorecode.py* uses the exact same sort of import but should be accessing the *utils* folder of *repo2*.

Comment: How someothercode imports utils?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is your problem, ideally via a [mcve]? Can you please clarify whether ``repo1``, ``repo2`` and ``utils`` are *packages* or just *folders*, and what imports are actually run? In specific, does ``main.py`` do ``import somemorecode`` or ``import repo2.somemorecode``, and likewise does ``somemorecode.py`` do ``import utils``, ``import repo2.utils`` or ``from . import utils``?

Comment: Take note that if ``repo1`` and ``repo2`` assume to have a top-level package ``utils`` then they are broken. Your best course of action is to fix them, ideally in the source repositories. If you really need both to co-exist in the same application, then modifying ``sys.path`` and ``sys.modules`` before importing each repo works, *provided the repo code does not inspect the import machinery or imports dynamically*.

Comment: Alternatively, *iff* neither ``utils/__init__.py`` contains code *and* there are no nameclashes inside ``utils``, then removing ``utils/__init__.py`` turns both folders into a single namespace package that merges the content of both. As with the previous suggestion, *this highly depends on how well-behaved ``repo1``/``repo2`` are*.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `as` keyword. It allows you to give custom name to imported module/object.

```
from repo1 import utils as repo1_utils
from repo2 import utils as repo2_utils
```

Then just call whatewer you need by accessing this new name that you've specified:

```
repo1_utils.some_function()
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't solve my problem, as it is the imports within the repos that are causing problems, and those I am not allowed to edit. E.g. `from utils.file import function1, function2` results in `No module named 'utils.file'`